# Profiling Sinatra with rack-perftools_profiler (using net/http)

Tags: ruby, http, profiling, sinatra, rack

One of my Sinatra actions performs another request using `net/http` and computes something based on the response:

```
api_response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

It works like a charm, but when I try to profile this:

```
configure do
  use ::Rack::PerftoolsProfiler, default_printer: 'pdf', frequency: 4000, mode: :walltime
end
```

(and put `?profile=true` into the params of the request I get this:

```
Errno::EADDRINUSE - Address already in use - connect(2):
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    /Users/tomek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:454:in `get_response'
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: I'm guessing from the error "Address already in use", something else is using the port your trying to run your profiler on. Make sure your not running something else on the same port.

Comment: Is it possible to setup profiler on a specific port?

Comment: Try changing Sinatra's port with `set :port, 9494`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I try to setup these the same way as you.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/perftools_profiler'
require 'net/http'

configure do
  use ::Rack::PerftoolsProfiler, default_printer: 'pdf', frequency: 4000, mode: :walltime
end

get "/" do
  uri = URI('http://google.com')
  api_response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
end
```

And it run with out a problem on ruby 1.9.3-p286 and with rack-perftools_profiler (0.6.1).

Two recommendations:

- update your ruby version
- update your gems

If these don't help check which program has bound your port with `sudo netstat -nlp`

If these all don't help please tell us more about your setup.